# Determine SSL connection behind a load balancer

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

Looking for best practice here.  We deal with SSL connection at our load balancer level and hence all the connection from our load balancer to our web servers are http.  With that we have no way of telling what kind of connection the client is making to our web server since all connection is through http.  We currently have 2 solution, one is to have the load balancer to append a port number in the URL string so that we can determine the kind of request (ex. 80 for http and 443 for https).  The other solution is for the load balancer to append a special header when it get https request so the web servers knows the type of connection.

Do you see cons in both solution?  Is there any best practice regarding SSL being applied at the load balancer level instead of web server level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the header, I think.  Adding something in the URL creates the possibility, however slim, that you'll collide with a query string parameter that an app wants to use.  A custom header would be easier.

A third option could be to have ssl connections redirect to a different port, say 8080, so on the back end you know that port 80 connections were http to begin with, and port 8080 connections were 443 to begin with, even though they're both http at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the header. A related concept is determining the IP address of the client (for logging purposes), since all requests to your web server appear to originate at the load balancer. The [`x-forwarded-for`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header is customarily used here.